# Should I use the implicit grant type or authorization code grant type?

Tags: spring, angular, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have a single page web app that I am trying to secure with OAuth 2. Ideally, I would not like to serve any static resources until the user has been authenticated with the authorization server. Is this possible to do with the implicit grant type? If not, are there security ramifications for using the authorization code grant type with a single page web app?

Comment: What do you mean by the static resources? I think your application itself is a static resource and you probably want it to be loaded first to initiate the authentication.

Comment: Yes, I have a spring boot application that is serving the single page web app. I am building the front end code and then copying the output over to my static folder in my spring boot app. However, I want the user to be authenticated before I give them the front end code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the static resources secured, you need to use cookies (browser sends them with each request). The easiest way is to use a session, where Spring Security can store it's authentication info. You cannot use the Implicit grant for your server application, because the hash part of the URL (containing a token) is not sent from browser to your server. So you need to use the Authentication code grant.

You need to configure Spring security with the `spring-security-oauth2` module to require authentication for your single page web app (SPA). You check [some tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/).

If you give up the idea of protecting static resources, you could use the Implicit flow in your SPA an keep the backend stateless.

Comment: Thank you! In your opinion, is it important to protect the static resources?

Comment: I think it's not necessary. You should not have any secret info in your sources and if you want the code to be unreadable, use obfuscation. By adding the security rules to your Spring application, you also bind the SPA and its backend so they have to be deployed together, which can be limiting.